# Why execvp accepts 2 arguments

Tags: c, linux, exec

Assume the following code in c:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
  char *args[] = {"/bin/echo", "1", NULL};
  execvp(args[0], args);
}
```

Why does `execvp` accept 2 arguments? Why can't it be `execvp(args)` and internally it would automatically grab the executable to run from `args[0]` ?

Comment: If `argv[0]` is `/bin/echo`, why are you bothering with `execvp()`?  Using `execv()` would be more sensible.

Comment: Because it's more clearly to read and understand. And also, there are two different arguments type, so it should not be combined into one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What if you want the "name" of the process (`args[0]` in your case) to be different from the actual executable program? That is a valid use-case, and the simplest solution to handle both the cases is the two-argument `execvp` we now have.

Comment: A classic example: a login shell was indicated by `argv[0]` containing a dash `-` — e.g. `/bin/-sh` or `/bin/-ksh` (or just `-sh` or `-ksh`) — yet the first argument to `execv()` or `execvp()` needed to be a file that existed — `/bin/sh` or `/bin/ksh`.